# How to print line before pattern using sed

Tags: sed

Having a text like below

```
Job {
  Name = testbox_db_weekly        ### for weekly full backup
  Type = Backup
  Client = testbox.domain.com-fd
  FileSet = testbox_fileset_weekly
  Schedule = testbox_cycle_weekly
  Storage = testbox_File
  Pool = testbox_two_week_weekly
  Messages = Standard
  Allow Mixed Priority = yes
  Max Run Sched Time = 86400
}
```

After searching the pattern using "testbox_db_weekly" it has to print before line i.e. "Job {" and then up to the end of the line i.e "}"

When searching using below pattern, not able to get before line.

```
job_output=$(sed -n "/$job_name/,\${p;/^}/q}"  $file_name)
```

Tried to hold  buffer with pattern space by using the "x" command but it is not working.

Please let me know how to achieve the solution

Comment: Does it __have to__ be sed?

Answer (score 1):

> it has to print before line i.e. "Job {" and then up to the end of the line i.e "}"

Then you can't use `/$job_name/,$` because you have to firstly detect `Job{ ... }` and put that into hold buffer, and then check the hold buffer against the job. Ie. you do not operate on `$job_name`, but operate on chunks from `Job {` to `}`.

```
sed '
    # Add a line to hold space
    H
    # If job ended
    /}/{
        # if hold space has a job print it
        x;
        /'"$job_name"'/p
        # Clear hold space
        s/.*//
        x;
    }
    d
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/testbox_db_weekly/p}' file
```

As this is a filtering operation turn off implicit printing `-n`.

Gather up lines between braces and then test the collection for the job name `testbox_db_weekly` and if found print the result.

An alternative solution that does as you specifically requested:

```
sed '$!N;/\n.*= testbox_db_weekly/!D;:a;n;/}/!ba' file
```

For all lines except the last, append the following line.

If the following line does not contains the the job name `testbox_db_weekly` delete the first line and repeat.

Otherwise, form a loop printing all other lines until one containing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk -v name='testbox_db_weekly' '
    $0 ~ ("Name *= *"name) {
        print prev
        f = 1
    }
    f {
        print
        if ( /}/ ) {
            exit
        }
    }
    { prev = $0 }
' file
```